# How to customize a site hosted on wordpress.com locally

Tags: customization, localhost, wordpress.com-hosting

I have a website on wordpress.com. Is there a way to download it to my localhost, customize it and then upload it back to wordpress.com?

Thanks

Comment: What are you customizing? Theme options, the content, custom CSS, or everything?

Comment: The customization will after the HTML, CSS and also JavaScript

Comment: Are you sure all the stuff you need to edit can be done on wordpress.com? Anything outside of theme options (& the [custom design premium feature](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/)) you won't be able to re-upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress com doesn't allow you to upload any customization, other than CSS via their paid customization feature.

Notably you can *download* WordPress com themes (link is available in sidebar of theme info page) and use them in self hosted installation. However, given that WP com doesn't provide source for much of its environment, it's unlikely that you would be able to replicate features and customization process precisely.

In a nutshell you need to go with self hosted installation for real freedom of customization.